# Link to the latest post with pagination

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm building a board and I have a list of all the sections. And in these sections are threads. In this list of sections I want to link to the latest post in a thread.

The problem is that I have a pagination for the posts.

Right now I can already link to the thread where the latest post is with..

```
<a href="{{ route('get_thread', [$section->id, App\Test\Helpers::lastPost($section)->thread->id]) }}">Latest Post</a>
```

and the custom method `lastPost()` is..

```
public static function lastPost($section)
{
    $threads = $section->threads;

    $thread_ids = [];
    foreach($threads as $thread) {
        array_push($thread_ids, $thread->id);
    }

    $posts = Post::whereIn('thread_id', $thread_ids)->get();

    return $posts->last();
}
```

But I do not know how I can link it to the page if the post is for example on `?page=2` ..

How I can do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've done it like that now..

First I created another method..

```
public static function lastPostPage($thread)
{
    $posts = $thread->posts;

    // The pagination number you've set
    $threadPagination = 6;

    // Count number of posts in thread
    $countPosts = count($posts);

    // Divide the number of posts by the pagination number
    $lastPageNumber = round($countPosts / $threadPagination);

    return "?page=" . $lastPageNumber;
}
```

Then I changed the link in the template..

```
<a href="{{ route('get_thread', [$section->id, App\Test\Helpers::lastPost($section)->thread->id]) . App\Test\Helpers::lastPostPage(App\Test\Helpers::lastPost($section)->thread) }}">Latest Post</a>
```

With that I get a link like this..

```
http://example.com/board/1/1?page=3
```

It's not the cleanest way, but it work! Maybe there is another way.

Someone on [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/link-to-the-latest-post/replies/76691) helped me.